# Qlik Sense change measure used on graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, qliksense

I'm using the svgReader extension (http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project/56728f52d1e497241ae69868) but I need a way for the user to switch between different measures used in the visualisation without changing sheets.

If I can change the sort order of the measures or replace the definition of a measure e.g. Sum([Sales]) to Sum([Margin]), this will update the graphic as needed. I have added some buttons to the visualisation however I'm struggling to understand how I can call a function do this.

I've read through much of the documentation available on the Qlik website but no success so far, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: a better place to look for answers is on the github page for the extension https://github.com/brianwmunz/svgReader-QlikSense - extensions by their nature fall outside of normal sense support. A question to ask would be if there are any plans to include alternative measures in the chart (a new feature in the latest version of Sense)

Comment: The problem is not extension specific, I just mentioned it in the post to provide context in case it was helpful. I just need a way to change the measure used in a visualisation or change the sort order via script.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Sense? As per the video Sense now allows alternative measures to be selected by users https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9TF3lH1Gog

Comment: Thanks, I've upgraded this has now allowed measures to be changed via the new exploration menu for the built-in visualisations however I still can't trigger this behaviour via script with buttons as I was hoping for. This new menu is also not available for extensions which we use heavily so I still need some alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by expression is in the below location in Sense

[image]

Comment: I need to change the order of the measures under the "measures" section, not the order of the values within a measure. 

For example if I add sales and then margin to a visualisation as measures, sales is 1st in this list, if I could alter this order and change margin to 1st it would solve my problem as the visualisation uses the first measure.

Comment: Can you drag the margin to the top of the list?

Comment: I can in edit mode, but users will not have access to edit mode to do this

Comment: @MarkJones did you resolve this? in normal view on the latest version of sense, if you hover over a chart you can see the exploration menu which allows users to make the changes to sorting.